# Hardware in Iran

Tags: legal, electronic-items, iran, prohibited-items

I will travel to Iran for a few weeks and I wanted to know if I can bring the two USB keys I always have with me:

- One with Tails OS installed on it.
- The other with two partitions, with one encrypted.

I guess both are forbidden. But as a tourist, can I have trouble just by having this on me (no matter the contents of the key)? How likely is it that during a control (at the border, in airports...) they check what is on the keys?

Comment: "I guess both are forbidden" You guess or do you have a reference saying that they are forbidden ? what's tails ?

Comment: Do you mean that it has Tails OS on it?

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about? Are you more concerned about just *having* an encrypted partition, or are you worried about the actual contents of the keys?

Comment: You'd better read the ITAR rules (assuming you are travelling to Iran after having been in the USA), a lot of software and electronics falls under "dual use".

Comment: I've never seen the content of electronic devices being checked in the airport in Iran. Only passport check. So no worries, unless you are a specific person they are after!

Comment: Can you explain why you think either of those might be forbidden?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.